# Setting number from xml in java

Tags: java, android

```
package com.android.SMStest;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Context;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SMStestActivity extends Activity {
private TextView txtPhoneNo;
private EditText txtMessage;
private Button btnSendSMS;
private EditText smsamount;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    smsamount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.smsamount);
    btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
    txtPhoneNo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
    TextView textgetLine1Number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
    // retrieve a reference to an instance of TelephonyManager
    final TelephonyManager phonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    textgetLine1Number.setText(getLine1Number());

    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String phoneNo = phonyManager.getLine1Number().toString();
            txtPhoneNo.setText(phoneNo);
            String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
            if (phoneNo.length() > 0 && message.length() > 0)
                sendSMS(phoneNo, message);
            else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

// ---sends an SMS message to another device---
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    int i;
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    }

}

public String getLine1Number() {
    return ((TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE))
            .getLine1Number();
    }
}
```

I am using this to enable the app I am making to send a certain amount of text messages to the phones MDN to stress test the sms capabilities. The problem I am running into is getting the number the user enters in the UI to actually control how many sms the app sends. The way I have it now will send the set amount of sms set in the programming with for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {. I need to be able to make this accept what the user enters so they can set their own amount. I have tried it as an integer with private Integer, but the app just force closes when you click the send sms button. I have tried to use getText().toString(), but it keeps telling me to set it as an integer. Any ideas to help an android newbie out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the string, so just change:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

to:

```
int amount = 10; // just making 10 the default if the EditText has an invalid value
try {
    amount = Integer.parseInt(smsamount.getText().toString());
}
catch (NumberFormatException) {}

for (i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much, worked like a charm :). The only thing I had to do a little different was to change catch (NumberFormatException) {}, to 
 catch (NumberFormatException smsamount) {}.